# Can I associate my AskUbuntu account with my other Stack Exchange accounts, for migrated questions?

Tags: support

I answered a question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), which was then [migrated to AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73601/ubuntu-guest-account-files-lost-how-to-recover#325957). Then, in agreement with a suggestion for improvement by another user posted in a comment, I decided to edit my post. I don't yet have editing privileges on AskUbuntu (to edit other people's posts--I can edit my own posts). So my edits are pending approval, because the question was posted by "another" user (Eliah Kagan on Server Fault, rather than Eliah Kagan here on AskUbuntu).

In the future, is there something I can do to *associate* my ServerFault and AskUbuntu accounts, so that if my question or answer or comment on one is migrated to the other, I have the ability to perform actions with them that I would be able to perform on my own posts (like editing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they use the same "Authentication" methods then they'll be automerged/associated within a 48 hour period. The only way to really avoid that is to have an account setup and associated on [all the sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) that you think you'd be interested it :)

Comment: But is there any way to automerge/associate accounts with different authentication methods? For example, I use Launchpad OpenID for AskUbuntu, and Google OpenID for other StackExchange sites...

Comment: @EliahKagan You can add multiple sources for in your profile under the My Logins section. Simply add your Google account and they should become associated.